# PostGIS ST_EuclideanDistance() not working. Wrong upperleftx and y?

Tags: qgis, postgis, raster, distance, spatial-statistics

I'm trying to make this ST_EuclideanDistance() function work, but no success so far. I'm not getting the expected result because the raster seems to be drawn at a wrong location.

Documentation:
https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/PostGIS_Raster_SoC_Idea_2012/Distance_Analysis_Tools

Firstly, I'm considering this test page to test the function:
https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/PostGIS_Raster_SoC_Idea_2012/Distance_Analysis_Tools/test

When running the second test case:

```
CREATE TABLE test_source_raster_1 AS 
SELECT 
    1 AS rid, rast 
  FROM 
    (SELECT 
       ST_MakeEmptyRaster(10,10,0,0,1,1,0,0,4326) AS rast
     ) foo;
CREATE TABLE test_source_geometry_1 AS 
SELECT 
    generate_series(1,10) AS id,
    ST_RandomPoints(the_geom,10) AS the_geom 
  FROM 
    (SELECT 
       ST_SetSRID(ST_Extent(rast::geometry), 4326) AS the_geom 
    FROM test_source_raster_1) foo;
CREATE TABLE test_ref_raster_1 AS 
SELECT 
  1 AS rid, rast 
  FROM 
    (SELECT 
       ST_MakeEmptyRaster(10,10,0,0,1,1,0,0,4326) AS rast
    ) foo;
 CREATE TABLE test_eudist_1_a_i_1 AS 
   (SELECT 
      1 AS rid,
      ST_EuclideanDistance(
         rast,'32BF','public',                    
         'test_source_geometry_1', 'the_geom', True
       ) AS rast 
     FROM test_ref_raster_1);
```

I'm getting this result (every raster pixel is null):

[image: results]

And this is the expected result I should have gotten:
[image: expected]

Comment: I suggest you change the topic of the question since the problem is not in the euclideandistance but in the datasets not being in the expected position as you mention yourself.

Comment: That's an interesting page. AS ST_EuclideanDistance is not part of Postgis 2.2, afaik, you might get more answers on the the dev mailing list. Where does the source come from, as a matter of interest?

Comment: I have just tested the code from the pages that you gave, but it works fine for me. Can you tell us how you got the results plotted? Are you sure that the raster that you show has the correct y-direction?

Comment: Hey @tilt, I'm plotting the results with QGIS. But I'm sure the last raster result is not calculated well because when select the distinct values inside the pixels of the raster, I only get null values, so it's not a plotting problem. Also, if I call ST_MakeEmptyRaster passing 10 and 10 as upperleftx and upperlefty I get the right positioning but the result stays null. What version of Postgres and PostGIS are you using? Here it's 9.5.5 and 2.3.

Comment: Installed new Postgres 9.5.3 and PostGIS 2.2 and got the same BAD results. Just to make sure, how are you plotting the results @tilt?

Comment: I'm casting the raster into an envelope with rast::geometry. The resulting envelope geometry is aligning as expected with the points (viewed QGIS). How do you add your raster to QGIS? Is it an export from the database or do you use the dbmanager in QGIS?

Comment: I see your point now, the resulting raster is indeed filled with null-data which is not expected. As John mentioned, the mailinglist (postgis-devel) might be a good place to dig further. I'm using a custom build postgis-latest on postgres 9.6.

Comment: Either using QGIS DBManager or export to tiff, I got null values and a not aligned raster. I will check with the mail list

Comment: @JohnPowellakaBarça "get more answers on the the dev mailing list" - please, no, there is postgis-users

Comment: @mloskot. Apologies. This seemed obscure enough for developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a way to make it work! I still don't know exactly what is the error, though.

These are the weird things that I found and changed:

1. When calling st_CreateEmptyRaster, instead of setting upperleftx and upperlefty I'm actually passing bottomleftx and bottomlefty as values. This fixed the alignment. **But why?** Maybe because of using Web Mercator?
2. Inside the ST_EuclideanDistance() function, there is a custom function called ST_NearestGridCentroid() that uses ST_World**2**RasterCoordX(). However, PostGIS only has ST_World**To**RasterCoordX(). Somehow, when executing altogether, PostGIS wasn't raising an exception at this point. I've changed to use the right one.
3. There is another error inside of the ST_EuclideanDistance() that doesn't raise an exception and doesn't let the function work properly. However, I don't know what it is. I figured that out because instead of calling ST_EuclideanDistance() I'm directly calling ST_MapAlgebraFct() passing the right values to it and still using euclidean_distance_fct() as a callback function.

As I spent a lot of time trying to figure this out, and now that it is working well for me, I'm just moving on without knowing the exact reasons. I'd appreciate if someone could take a further look.

This is my final code (It's wrapped inside a Postgres function):

```
  v_rast_pixel_size = 50; -- 50 meters each pixel
  v_srid = 3857;

  -- The raster size and bounds will consider the extent of this geometry
  drop table if exists v_community_extent ;
  create temp table v_community_extent as
    select st_dumppoints(st_expand(st_extent(st_transform(shape, 3857)), 1000)) as dp from communities where name = 'Berlin';

  -- reference points to calculate the size of the extent
  SELECT (dp).geom into v_community_extent_minx_miny FROM (select * from v_community_extent) As foo where (dp).path[2] = 1;
  SELECT (dp).geom into v_community_extent_minx_maxy FROM (select * from v_community_extent) As foo where (dp).path[2] = 2;
  SELECT (dp).geom into v_community_extent_maxx_miny FROM (select * from v_community_extent) As foo where (dp).path[2] = 4;

  -- measuring how many pixels the raster will have
  v_rast_width = round(st_distance(v_community_extent_minx_miny, v_community_extent_maxx_miny) / v_rast_pixel_size) + 1;
  v_rast_height = round(st_distance(v_community_extent_minx_miny, v_community_extent_minx_maxy) / v_rast_pixel_size) + 1;

  -- Creating empty raster
  drop table if exists _tmp_ras_heatmap;
  create table _tmp_ras_heatmap as
    SELECT 1 as rid,
      ST_MakeEmptyRaster(
          v_rast_width::INTEGER, v_rast_height::INTEGER,
          st_x(v_community_extent_minx_miny)::DOUBLE PRECISION, st_y(v_community_extent_minx_miny)::DOUBLE PRECISION,
          v_rast_pixel_size, v_rast_pixel_size, 0, 0, v_srid
      ) AS rast;

  -- Initial Band and enabling QGIS visualization
  UPDATE _tmp_ras_heatmap SET rast = ST_AddBand(rast,'32BSI'::text, 0, -1);
  perform AddRasterConstraints('public'::name, '_tmp_ras_heatmap'::name, 'rast'::name,'srid','out_db','extent');


  drop table if exists _tmp_ras_heatmap_ed;
  CREATE TABLE _tmp_ras_heatmap_ed AS (
  SELECT 1 AS rid,
    ST_MapAlgebraFct(
        rast,null,'euclidean_distance_fct(float,integer[],text[])'::regprocedure,
        v_rast_width::text,v_rast_height::text,
        st_x(v_community_extent_minx_miny)::text,st_y(v_community_extent_minx_miny)::text,
        v_rast_pixel_size::text,v_rast_pixel_size::text,
        '0'::text, '0'::text,
        v_srid::text, '-1'::text,
        'public'::text,'source_points_table'::text,'shape'::text,
        true::text,'50000'::text
    ) AS rast FROM _tmp_ras_heatmap);
```